# Set min datepicker with time in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Am working on oracle apex project, I have two datepicker date with format DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM (p_from_date and p_to_date), need to set min date for p_to_date based on p_from_date value, am using the below javascript on p_from_date change dynamic action event:
**$('#p_to_date').datepicker("option","minDate",$("#p_from_date").val()).next('button').addClass('a-Button a-Button--calendar');**
it is working fine without time format "DD-MM-YYYY" but when adding time such as "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM" it is not working properly when navigate between months:
1-the time picker in the calendar is disappear
2-all pervious days before  p_from_date are enabled

is there any solution to set min date in   p_to_date based on p_from_date with time format like "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it.

Click on To_time

Go to Settings Find Minimum date.

Choose an item and select the From_date field as the Minimum date.

This will automatically disable less time than from time.

[Date Select Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWXLp.png)